# Downgrading Angular component for use in AngularJS hybride app

Tags: angular

I have some set of Angular components that I'd like to use in my AngularJS app. To achieve that, we have created an hybride application, we googled a lot and we achived that.

The next step is to downgrade our Angular component, and use it in AngulaJS code via the AngularJS directive, we read the Angular Team doc, and we started to google a lot... this time, it dosen't help.

I can have my simple Angular component in my AngularJS code. 
But I need the one that is not too stupide, so I have added some "ngIf" atribute to my dummy component, in the purpose to create a dependency on a "commonModule".

And, now I'm stuck with this error:

> scripts.js:57488 Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgForOf ->
>   ViewContainerRef]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgForOf ->
>   ViewContainerRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ViewContainerRef!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (vendor.js:147297)
>       at resolveToken (vendor.js:147542)
>       at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:147486)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (vendor.js:147383)
>       at resolveToken (vendor.js:147542)
>       at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:147486)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (vendor.js:147383)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:159619)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (vendor.js:160308)
>       at resolveDep (vendor.js:160679) ""

My working Angular component looks like:

```html
<span>
    <span>Hello World !</span>
</span>
```

I can see it in my hybrid AngularJS app.

My Angular component, having the dependency on commonModule:

```html
<span>
    <span>Hello World !</span>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let book of bookList">{{ book.name }}</li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * Only for tests
 */
@Component({
    selector: "test",
    templateUrl: "./test.component.html"
})
export class TestComponent {

    bookList = [
        {
            name: "eXtreme Programming Explained"
        },
        {
            name: "Clean Code"
        }
    ];

    public ngOnInit() {
        console.log("Hello My Test");
    }

}
```

I'm looking for any lead to import/downgrade/ingore the commonModule and make work my Anguar component in my JS app.

I